# How do I put a specific value on the bottom of a report in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to place a specific value of a report at the bottom of the report and I can't figure out how to do it. There is only one of these values in the database and I need to sort everything by one field EXCEPT this one value from another field which has to go on the bottom. I am using Access 2016

Comment: You need to give more details. How does you data look like, what is this special value, how does the report look like.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple to achieve. You need to create an artificial calculated column for the special condition and then sort by two values.

As you did not provide any information on your data structure, I make something up:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY IIF([AnotherField]='SpecialValue',1,0), NormalSortField
```

This will achieve your sorting requirements directly in a query. If you are grouping/sorting within the report, you should include that *IIF*-Expression in the output list and use it as first sort column before your *NormalSortField*.